# Run cURL commend from flutter

Tags: flutter, curl, dart

I need to know how to run the below cURL in Flutter.

```
curl -v -d '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}' --http2 --cert voip.pem:1234 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/287f063372970c602cf80f889e74d0000e06649e6872c077f24fe8ce7b624b9c
```

My understanding that I can use Dio package but I am not able to figure out how to include the certificate too. Henec, I hope there is sample for the code you can share.

Comment: The website here will convert most curl commands to dart. https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @RichardHeap - Thanks! Any idea of how to add the pem file in the url?

Comment: Ah, you need http2? Use the dart http2 package. Supply the pem to the secure socket connect method.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26954